# DD-WRT trying to connect to one of two SSIDs with same name

Tags: dd-wrt, ssid

There are two networks within my routers range with the same SSID. One is my friends who let's me use it and the other I don't know whose it is. They both have passwords off. My friend is kind is not computer savvy and is afraid of me messing around with his router to change the SSID name.

Is there a way to connect to an SSID with a specific MAC address so that I connect to the right SSID? By default it connects to the SSID that's not my friends.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions. Your question should go to superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ap` option of `iwconfig` to specify which to connect to.

Comment: Ignacio, I have no idea how to do what you've suggested. Can you be so kind and elaborate further.

Comment: `iwconfig` is the command to configure a wireless NIC. One of the arguments it takes, `ap`, specifies the address of the other device to connect to. See the `iwconfig(8)` man page for further details.